# Definition of Local Convex Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological linear space. **Is it true that the following equivalence hold?**

$(X,\tau)$ is a locally convex space $\Longleftrightarrow$ There is a familly of seminorms $\mathcal{P}=(p_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $\tau$ is exactly the initial topology generated on $X$ by the familly $p_i:X\to (\mathbb{R},\tau_0),\ i\in I$.

By initial topology I mean the coarsest topology on $X$ for which the maps $p_i:X\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.

In all text that I've found there is an ambiguity about that, because the local convex spaces are introduced via a given local base of the origin wrt a family of seminorms.

P.S. By $\tau_0$ I mean the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: [Not quite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284692/topology-induced-by-seminorms-and-initial-topology).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I see the difference!